# c# detect mousedown without controls

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I'm new in c# and want to code a click bot for a game, which should click when I hold my mouse button down and stop clicking when I'm releasing the mouse button. Now My question is how to check if a mouse button is held down and click when I'm in another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a message filter:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyMessageFilter());
```

where `MyMessageFilter` is a class implementing `IMessageFilter`. Example:

```
class MyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201, WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left button down " + DateTime.Now);
                return false;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Left button up " + DateTime.Now);
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you return `true`, this signals that you have processed the message and that you don't want any controls to get this message. I.e. `true` inactivates the corresponding Form or Control event.

The `HWnd` property of the `Message` structure returns the Window handle of the affected window.

Here, you can find a reference for [Mouse Input Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input-notifications).